# Exception unhandled when event is raised in dll (accessed using app domain)

Tags: c#, event-handling, appdomain, system.reflection

My project contains

1. windows form application(WindowsFormsApplication1)
2. dll (ClassLibrary1).

I am trying to implement some logic in my windows form application when an event is raised in my DLL. I am accessing DLL methods through AppDomain.

Below is the code in windows form
Form1.cs

```
using System;
// more usings ...
using ClassLibrary1;
using System.Reflection;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            trial obj = new trial();
            obj.trial1();
         }
      }

    class trial 
    {
        void HandleEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("HandleEvent called");
        }

         AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Test");
         string DLL = @"C:\..\ClassLibrary1.dll";
            
           public void trial1()
            {
                 trial pro = new trial();MethodInfo method = typeof(trial).GetMethod("HandleEvent", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

                // Subscribe to the event
                EventInfo eventInfo = typeof(ClassLibrary1.Class1).GetEvent("TestEvent");
                Type type = eventInfo.EventHandlerType;
                Delegate handler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(type, pro, method);
                // method call 1
                Loader.Call(ad, DLL,"ClassLibrary1.Class1","RaiseEvent",DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
            }
    }

    public class Loader : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        object CallInternal(string dll, string typename, string method, object[] parameters)
        {
            Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFile(dll);
            object o = a.CreateInstance(typename);
            Type t = o.GetType();
            MethodInfo m = t.GetMethod(method);
            return m.Invoke(o, parameters);
        }

        public static object Call(AppDomain domain, string dll, string typename, string method, params object[] parameters)
        {
            Loader ld = (Loader)domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, typeof(Loader).FullName);
            object result = ld.CallInternal(dll, typename, method, parameters);
            AppDomain.Unload(domain);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the code in ClassLibrary1.dll

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public event EventHandler TestEvent;

        public int RaiseEvent(string msg)
        {
            try
            {
                TestEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("the exception is: " + ex.ToString());
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("the inner exception is: " + ex.InnerException.Message.ToString());
                }
            }
            return 2;
         }
    }
}
```

It throws an exception when it runs `TestEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);`
The exception is

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

There are no issues when accessing the same event using a console application program.
The code in the console application program are as follows.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class Test
{
    void HandleEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HandleEvent called");
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Test test = new Test();
        ClassLibrary1.Class1 publisher = new ClassLibrary1.Class1();
        MethodInfo method = typeof(Test).GetMethod("HandleEvent", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        // Subscribe to the event
        EventInfo eventInfo = typeof(ClassLibrary1.Class1).GetEvent("TestEvent");
        Type type = eventInfo.EventHandlerType;
        Delegate handler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(type, test, method);

        eventInfo.AddEventHandler(publisher, handler);
        publisher.RaiseEvent("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: Outside all the unneccessary Marshalling and Reflection: Your Form instanciates an instance of `trial` only locally in its contructor. When the constructor is done, the instance will go out of scope and be garbage collected. And I think (it's very convoluted) you are not actually registering the EventHandler on the same instance that you raise the event on. That's why the NRE is thrown.

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea for you to go through this: [Events (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/)

Comment: There should be an AddEventHandler (target object, delegate) after creating the delegate. But I am not sure what to pass as target object in AddEventHandler

Comment: Usually you do `eventEmittingThing.SomeEvent += this.MySomeEventHandler;` and that's it.

Comment: Here the 'eventEmittingThing' will be an object of  'Class1' class. But in my winform I am not explicitly declaring object of type Class1. I am invoking the methods of Class1 using Loader class, as Class1 is loaded in AppDomain. I want the same instance to also handle the event. Is there a way to do it?